# Efficently sending Bitmaps over a Bluetooth Socket

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bitmap

I have a basic application that is able to send a Bitmap over a Bluetooth socket. They only issue is that the latency is astoundingly huge (around 20 seconds per image). In the application, the Client sends the bitmap and the Server receives the bitmap. The client gets the bitmap from a TextureView and runs:

```
byte[] data = BitmapDataObject.bytesFromBitmap(bitmapToSend);
Logger.logE("CLIENT got byte array");
os.write(data.length);
Logger.logE("CLIENT wrote length of data");
os.flush();
Logger.logE("CLIENT flushed data");
in.nextLine();
Logger.logE("CLIENT read a line");
os.write(data,0,data.length);
Logger.logE("CLIENT wrote array to buffer");
os.flush();
```

The `BitmapDataObject.bytesFromBitmap(bitmapToSend)` looks like

```
public static byte[] bytesFromBitmap(Bitmap map){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    map.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

The server receives the bitmap and parses it via `Bitmap map = BitmapDataObject.bitmapFromStream(is);`, which looks like

```
public static Bitmap bitmapFromStream(InputStream is){
    Bitmap decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(decoded, 100, 100, true);
}
```

I am looking for ways to optimize this. The resolution/quality of the Bitmap on the server side is not too important to me (although I'd like it to be at least 360p), and I'm willing to dive into the NDK if need be.

Comment: How much data is being sent? Is the time due to the size of the Bitmap or some fixed latency?

Comment: It's due to the size of the bitmaps being sent, I believe.